# What is df[0] in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

As a Just startup learner and student i'm working on the some basics and got into pandas read_html function, while searching through web I tried to get the data from html source via a url with below code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('http://prodserverlist/pod.html', header=0, flavor='bs4')
df1 = df[0]
```

I would like to know what what exactly `df[0]` in `df1 = df[0]`.

Comment: Sorry but SO is not a tutorial service, especially as [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) docs already has plenty of tutorials. Please read through those and when you have a specific problem come back and post that question

Comment: I'm sorry but this is way too broad for SO. See [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Pandas can be tough to learn, I suggest that you also follow the tag and get your head around the answers given. The docs don't always cover the ways that different methods can be combined to solve problems.

Comment: You should consider taking coursera courses or codeacademy for questions like this.

Comment: @EdChum, Thanks for your inputs, understand your concern, though i'm not really asking for tutorials just opinions , i'm already doing my homework just came across to demystify my understanding, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @d_kennetz and @roganjosg  I'm already going with coursera  & various other learning portals, precisely my doubt was on `df[0]`.

Comment: SO is also not an opinion-based service, it's focus is on direct and focused questions. `df[0]` simply refers to the first dataframe (index `0`) in the list of dataframes returned by `pd.read_html()`, per the docs.

Comment: @rahlf23, let me raised the direct Question then, thnx for your value inputs.

Comment: Sorry guys for inconvenience , I have edited the code directly to the Question.

Comment: This is really bad variable naming.  What is returned from read_html is a list of dataframes.   So, you really should use something like list_of_df = pd.read_html....  Then df = list_of_df[0], to get the first dataframe representing the first table in a webpage.

Comment: @ScottBoston, this  was just for test but your point is noteworthy i'll take this advise for all future considerations.

Comment: as a sidenote: df[0] is senseless and should throw an error, provided df is a DataFrame (should be a DataFrame) and not a list of DataFrames (should not be a list!). In the example above "df" should be renames to something like 'dfs' or 'df_list'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, `df[0]` simply refers to the first dataframe (index `0`) in the list of dataframes (`df`) returned by `pd.read_html()`, per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html):

> This function searches for `<table>` elements and only for `<tr>` and `<th>` rows and `<td>` elements within each `<tr>` or `<th>` element in the table. `<td>` stands for “table data”.
>
> This function will always return a list of DataFrame or it will fail, e.g., it will not return an empty list.